# plist data not been updated and saved when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have a "Settings" plist file with some values in. I'm trying to read in the plist and then make an update to one of these settings. When I reload my app the update has not taken effect and the original setting is still there.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSMutableDictionary *settings = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!settings) NSLog(@"error reading plist: %@ , format: %lu", errorDesc, format);
```

// update object

```
[settings setObject:@"0" forKey:@"£50"];
[settings writeToFile:@"Settings.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: `@"Settings.plist"` is not a correct _path_ for a file.

Comment: Just asking, is this plist included in your app bundle?  If so, it is immutable (on real devices).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to lie here.

```
[settings writeToFile:@"Settings.plist" atomically:YES];
```

This is the incorrect path for the plist. If I change it to

```
[settings writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If this plist does what it implies (stores settings), [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is made for just that without having to deal with the file system.